# RelativeLayout image size?

Tags: android, image, android-relativelayout

What is an image size for Background image having RelativeLayout?
Whenever using image the app shows the message, Unfortunatelly, app has stopped.

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        layout_main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        main_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_text_0);
        main_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#335033"));
        main_text.setFocusable(false);
        main_text.setEnabled(false);
        layout_main.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
        addclicklistener();
```

Answer (score 1):

Move this line:

> ```
> layout_main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
> ```

below this line:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to avoid `NullPointerException` and resulting: "Unfortunately app has stopped" message.

Your `drawable` will be resized to fill `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing **layout_main** before **setContentView**,

```
layout_main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

**First define setContentView and then initialize layout_main like this:**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

layout_main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
```